# How to fix the partitions' number on GPT disk (/dev/sdaX)

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I used Gparted to delete EFI (/dev/sda1) and Ubuntu (/dev/sda2) partitions on my secondary drive. The third partition (/dev/sda3) is for data, so I resized it in order to use all unallocated space I've got by deleting the first two partitions. Now, having only a unique partion on the disk, I would like to fix it's number, in order to get /dev/sda1.
What's the easiest way to do it that works with a disk having GPT partition table? 
Thank you!

Comment: You do know that renumbering is just beautification for your own eyes, right? Anyway... you should have resized /dev/sda1 to be bigger than /dev/sda3. Then copy sda3 over sda1.  File check sda1 and if no problems, remove sda3, resize sda1 accordingly.

Comment: By the way... you said sda is your secondary drive ?  Then what it the primary known as?

Comment: What does primary drive has to do with it?
My question is about /dev/sda drive. I said "secondary" because there is not Ubuntu installed anymore and so dev/sdb has become the primary one  where I have Windows 10 installed.

Comment: Nothing, I was just curious. It is usual for sda to be primary drive.

Comment: You are right. I have to reverse the SATA connectors on my motherboard. :)
Anyway, any suggestions to fix the number? The situation is that, I didn't mind to do as you explained! :D

Comment: Before you do anything, I forgot to mention: MAKE A BACKUP of your important files. Next, see my answer. If you create a partition before sda3, it will restart the numbering. The new sda1 must be bigger than sda3 to accommodate the partition copy. So you may have to shrink sda3 and move it to the right.

Comment: Well, sd3 is the data partition, so the biggest one. 
Deleting the other two partitions, I got about 20 Gb unallocated space, so it moved sd3 to the left (it took about six hours). 
It worked, so I have a unique partition, named sda3. I checked all data and they are safe! :D

Comment: Oh oh... You said "moved sd3 to the left". Which is NOT what we want. We need space BEFORE sd3. Are you sure you want to spend another 6 hours to move sd3 to the RIGHT? Plus another 6 hours copying the partition?? For Ubuntu it makes no difference what the partition number is. Like I said, it is just a beautification.

Comment: No man, I had to "move to the left" as the result of extending sd3 using unallocated space on the left. It's of course on the left because the two partitions I deleted were before sd3! 
Anyway, everything worked, because I've got sd3 extended, exactly what I wanted!
You know, my original question is different! :D

Comment: Ok. If you are happy with your new partition then all is good. Please "Answer your own question and Approve it"  so is can be closed.

Comment: I'm happy with my new partition of course but not with it's number! :D
I'm interested in renumbering it and I would like to know how to do it, that is my question. ;)

Comment: Well... I have been using Linux for 25+ years now, so I started writing "You cannot"... but just to be thorough (many things happen in 25 years) I did a Google search and I was very surprised to find that somebody has a solution: `https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18752/change-the-number-of-the-partition-from-sda1-to-sda2`. I feel I must warn you it is a very risky exercise, which may corrupt your whole disk. So don't blame me if your disk does die on you. So: GOOD LUCK !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use `gdisk` to rewrite the partition-table:

```
sudo gdisk /dev/sda
p  (the p-command prints the recent partition-table on-screen)
s  (the s-command sorts the partition-table entries)
p  (use the p-command again to see the result on your screen)
w  (write the changed partition-table to the disk)
q  (quit gdisk)
```

You will find most useful information about `gdisk` at http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/

Comment: Before I found your answer, I used fdisk to rewrite the patition-table: sudo fdisk /dev/sdb and then, in this order, x-f-r-w. It worked like a charm, getting /dev/sdb1 as I expected. I can deduce that using either fdisk or gdisk command is exactly the same and that fdisk command is proper for GPT patition-table too, is it?

Comment: @Generoso Older versions of `fdisk` didn't support GPT, recent version does, probably `fdisk` uses `gdisk` in a way, difficult to find  deeper insight... I wouldn't have tried it with `fdisk`, but good to know that it works too. +1 for your effort...

Comment: Understood! :)
Anyway, if I try to use gdisk, after I press s, it says: "You may need to edit /etc/fstab and/or your boot loader configuration". 
What about this message?

Comment: @Generoso If you mount your partition via fstab you should check if the related fstab-entry is still valid. Your boot-loader configuration shouldn't be affected as the partition doesn't contain the OS but only data.

Comment: Ok, so it's just a warning. I thought there was a problem with it and the command didn't work. 
I simply used Ubuntu 17.04 on a bootbale pendrive selecting "Try Ubuntu" and I used gdisk command without mounting the partition. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it is just a warning, `gdisk` can't know what the purpose of the partition is, and gently gives this message. If you auto-mount your partition in your installed OS you should care about and check fstab-entry for validity after the changes. Imagine you auto-mount `/dev/sda3` instead of using UUID, fstab-entry would fail because `sda3` doesn't exist anymore. If you don't auto-mount  the partition in any  OS then you don't need to care.

Comment: This is something we have to take care every time  we edit partitions, moving partitions around or sorting partition-table-entries may lead to  funny situations, in the worst case we are not able to boot the machine due to changes we made. It doesn't depend on the tool we use to edit the partitions. In your case I don't expect any problems...

Comment: FWIW, I'm the author of `gdisk` and AFAIK `fdisk` does *not* rely on `gdisk` in any way. (It's conceivable the `fdisk` developers "borrowed" some code from `gdisk` -- which would be fine -- but this is unlikely because `gdisk` is written in C++ and `fdisk` is written in C.) I modeled `gdisk`'s user interface on `fdisk` back in the days when `fdisk` didn't support GPT; but the `fdisk` developers took a different path in handling GPT-specific features, so the two programs' user interfaces have diverged.

Answer (score 1):

Intrigued by finding that last link and keen learning something new, I replayed Generoso's partition situation on my system using a 32GB USB drive. Below are my findings, but first my:

Conclusion: As my example is aimed at 1 (final) partition, near the end I merely changed its name. I did not touch the actual sectors. In the link in my comment above, an example is shown where sector number are moved around. I followed that and miserably goofed and destroyed the USB disk, proving how dangerous playing with partitions really is !!
Maybe my scenario also works with multiple partitions, feel free to try it yourself. I dare you to use your primary partition for it.. haha.
Ok, here are my:

Findings:
Using Gparted I created 3 partitions, each 1 GB.

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 30 GiB, 32176472064 bytes, 62844672 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf33657fc

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1          2048 2099199 2097152   1G 83 Linux
/dev/sdc2       2099200 4196351 2097152   1G 83 Linux
/dev/sdc3       4196352 6293503 2097152   1G 83 Linux
```

Using Disks to mount partition 3.
Manually placed a file on it.

```
# ls -l /media/willem/cd4746ac-6d9f-4057-9396-a593ce2f301d/
total 21436
drwx------ 2 root root    16384 May 27 00:12 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21930117 May 27 00:14 SomeFile.txt
```

Using Disks to unmount partition 3.
Using Gparted to remove partitions 1 & 2 and grow partition 3 to use the whole disk.

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 30 GiB, 32176472064 bytes, 62844672 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf33657fc

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdc3        8192 62844671 62836480  30G 83 Linux
```

Using Disks to mount partition 3.
Check the file on partition 3.

```
# ls -l /media/willem/cd4746ac-6d9f-4057-9396-a593ce2f301d/
total 21436
drwx------ 2 root root    16384 May 27 00:12 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21930117 May 27 00:14 SomeFile.txt
```

Using Disks to unmount partition 3.
Copy the partition table from the drive.
Show the partition table.

```
# sfdisk -d /dev/sdc > sdc.tab
# cat sdc.tab
label: dos
label-id: 0xf33657fc
device: /dev/sdc
unit: sectors

/dev/sdc3 : start=        8192, size=    62836480, type=83
```

Using `vi sdc.tab` to change sdc3 into sdc1.
Apply the changed partition table.

```
# sfdisk --no-reread -f /dev/sdc < sdc.tab
Disk /dev/sdc: 30 GiB, 32176472064 bytes, 62844672 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf33657fc

Old situation:

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdc3        8192 62844671 62836480  30G 83 Linux

>>> Script header accepted.
>>> Script header accepted.
>>> Script header accepted.
>>> Script header accepted.
>>> Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xf33657fc.
Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 30 GiB.
/dev/sdc2: 
New situation:

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        8192 62844671 62836480  30G 83 Linux

The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

As soon as the command finishes, partition 1 auto-mounts.
Check the file.

```
# ls -l /media/willem/cd4746ac-6d9f-4057-9396-a593ce2f301d/
total 21436
drwx------ 2 root root    16384 May 27 00:12 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21930117 May 27 00:14 SomeFile.txt
```

Using Disks to unmount partition 1.
Done.

PS. I did `cat SomeFile.txt` every time but I felt it unnecessary to include that output.

Comment: Man, thank you for your detailed answer! 
Anyway, I solved my problem by using fdisk command. 
It's very very simple. Take a look to keep in mind if you will need it in future.

Answer (score 0):

You should have resized /dev/sda1 to be bigger than /dev/sda3. Then copy sda3 over sda1. File check sda1 and if no problems, remove sda3, resize sda1 accordingly.

Comment: As `/dev/sda1` was a (presumably FAT) ESP and `/dev/sda3` already contained user data (perhaps FAT, but I'd guess not), doing *exactly* as you suggest might mean changing the filesystem type. That said, depending on the partitions' sizes, creating a *new* `/dev/sda1` with the right filesystem type, copying the files over, deleting `/dev/sda3`, and then resizing `/dev/sda1` might have been slightly safer than moving the start point of `/dev/sda3`. Of course, this is all moot now to the OP.