# Skipped sda partition numbers

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

I'm preparing to change my partition layout on my dual boot notebook (using gparted). The notebook works fine now.

I have a bunch of partitions (GPT) on the 1TB SSD in my notebook. They are numbered sda1 - sda9 and sda12. Apparently, there are no sda10 and sda11 partitions at all. I thought that sda's were assigned dynamically and that there would be no numbering gaps. What's going on here?

I'm fairly confident (although a bit rusty) with gparted, so I'm not asking for help designing or doing the repartitioning. I do want to know if having the missing sda's means I have a problem to resolve. This notebook is my primary computer and I can't afford to have it be unusable for any extended length of time.

Background: My main OS is kubuntu 18.04 with root on sda4 and home on sda5.
sda1 - 3 are EFI, microsoft/grub2, and swap. Windows 10 was deleted a long time ago.
sda6 and 7 are going to be my new root and home for kubuntu 22.04, so I can keep using 18.04 until everything is installed, configured, and tested. That takes a long time for me to do.
sda8 and 9 are old root and home partitions that will be deleted with the space added to the other partitions.
sda12 is my data partition that uses the rest of the disk. It's configured to automount.

This is what I have in my /etc/fstab:

```
LABEL=root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
LABEL=home /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda10 during installation
UUID=3ef9528c-1927-40fd-8729-33506d440101 none            swap    sw              0       0
## automount dataspace - JJP
LABEL=dataspace /media/dataspace  ext4    auto,rw,suid,exec,async,atime 0 1
```

Here's what gparted sees.

[image: Gparted screenshot]

While searching for answers to this, I saw a comment that said I shouldn't have a swap partition on an SSD. Is this something I also need to address?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with "missing" partition numbers, but it is possible to fix it, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/919218/590937). But not necessary at all.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong about "missing" partition numbers.

For example if you create 4 partitions (sda1, sda2, sda3, sda4) and remove sda3, it will be "missing".

So there is nothing to fix.